# Create a multi-pane layout with a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I wanted to convert my app to a version that supports larger screens like tablets.  My app consist of a ListView with a custom ListViewAdapter and if you select one of the items in the list you go to a new FragmentActivity that shows some extra information about the selected listitem. In the FragmentActivity I have a pager that holds 4 different Fragments and you can switch between these fragments.

What I want is that if the user is using a tablet, is that the listview and the FragmentActivity are beside eachother and the FragmentActivity gets updated when the user selects different items from the listview. Now I looked online how this works and I need to use fragments, but can't find anything about FragmentActivities.

How do I make it work with a FragmentActivity?

Comment: As a starting point you can create a new project in eclipse or android studio and use the template for a multi-pane layout and see how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc C suggests, a multi-pane layout of exactly the kind it sounds like you want can be created if you create a New Android Application, and near the end of the New Android Project wizard, you choose "Master/Detail Flow" in the Create Activity page. (Note: You'll need to target a minimum SDK version of 11 or above to choose that but that should be OK I guess if you're targetting tablets).

In your new project, you'll get a DetailActivity.java – this is a FragmentActivity that represents the item detail side of the app. The content all comes from a DummyContent list class which holds DummyItem objects, created (via a static) in the ListFragment onCreate - this fragment represents the list view which will be shown on the left on large enough screens.

In a tablet side-by-side layout, tapping an item in the list on the left results in a call to ListActivity.onItemSelected - this creates the detail fragments that show the detailed content - the content you currently have in your pager. In a single pane layout, then the detail activity is started by intent, which you can see also in onItemSelected.

So you'd need to replace the instantiation of the DetailFragment class in the DetailActivity.onCreate and within the ListActivity.onItemSelected with instantiation of your your current fragments from the pager. I imagine you can adapt and re-use the ListFragment instead of trying to plumb in your existing ListView and adaptor code, depends on what you have in there and what other requirements you have though.